# Read from CSV file and insert into database Python

Tags: python, database, list, csv, indexing

I am trying to read a CSV file and insert into a PostgreSQL database. But I want 1st and 5th column item as integer. So, I am converting 1st and 5th columns into an integer. But it is showing error <    date_2 = int(row[0])

IndexError: list index out of range>

```
    with open('parts_time.txt') as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in readCSV:

            date_2 = int(row[0])
            date_4 = int(row[4])

            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO parts_time 
            (time_id,time_day,time_month,time_year,vendor_idk)"\
            "VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
           [date_2,row[1],row[2],row[3],date_4])
```

Comment: You probably have an empty line at the end of the file

Comment: is the header in csv same to the headers in table ?

Answer (score 1):

Try processing the row only if there is something inside:

```
with open('parts_time.txt') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        if row:
            date_2 = int(row[0])
            date_4 = int(row[4])

            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO parts_time 
            (time_id,time_day,time_month,time_year,vendor_idk)"\
            "VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
            [date_2,row[1],row[2],row[3],date_4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your file contains empty lines due to that your getting **IndexError**
Try this.

```
with open('t.txt') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        if len(row) != 5:
            continue
        date_2 = int(row[0])
        date_4 = int(row[4])
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO parts_time (time_id,time_day,time_month,time_year,vendor_idk) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)" % tuple([date_2,row[1],row[2],row[3],date_4]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is because of your improper data in csv.
While dealing with csv files i always use `pandas`. By this you don't have to think about the issues like you are facing, it will automatically resolve it for you.
Clubbing that with the `executemany`, will make your code run faster.

```
import pandas
df = pd.read_csv('parts_time.txt')
df.columns = ['time_id', 'time_day', 'time_month', 'time_year', 'vendor_idk'] # You can skip this line if the column names in csv file matches that in Database
df['time_id'] = df['time_id'].astype(int)
df['vendor_idk'] = df['vendor_idk'].astype(int)
cursor.prepare("insert into parts_time(time_id,time_day,time_month,time_year,vendor_idk) values(:1, :2, :3 ,:4, :5)")
cursor.executemany(None, df.values.tolist())
```